# Arp spoofing not working against iPhone, iPad, or Mac

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, arp

I have an iPhone 4 and iPad 3 both running iOS 7.0.4 and MacBook Pro Retina running OS 10.9.1.  I want to write a sniffer program, and have been trying to ARP spoof these devices, but their traffic does not seem to be appearing in Wireshark.  I have tried using both `arpspoof` and `ettercap` for this spoofing, running each from both my Mac and a fully updated Kali Linux machine.  I am certain that ip forwarding is enabled on both of these machines and certain that both are fully capable of this spoofing because it works fine on both when targeting a Windows machine on the same network.  Are Apple devices just immune to ARP attacks?  Is there something I can do to usurp this immunity?